# Select-String and Exclude? NotMatch?

Tags: powershell

I need to select strings from a log file, if they start with the pattern "FATAL:" but NOT if they contain the entire line of "FATAL: SystemCallError: The interface is unknown. - RegisterEventSource" (as this is an error that pops up every time a system reboots, I want to exclude these lines from the select-string results).  I currently have the code searching for all strings that start with "FATAL:", but I am not sure how to have it exclude this if the entire line matches the one above that I referenced.  I was hoping to use Select-String and exclude or notmatch somehow.  Here is my current code:

```
$fatalerrors = Select-String -Pattern "FATAL:" -Path $cheflogfile
```

I need to somehow NOT include lines that are EXACTLY this:

```
"FATAL: SystemCallError: The interface is unknown. - RegisterEventSource"
```

Also of note - all lines that I would be searching for begin with "FATAL:".  I think that is where I am getting tripped up. Not entirely sure.

Comment: Examples always help. Please show some sample input as well as the output you expect from that and the output you actually get.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
gc $cheflogfile | ?{ $_.StartsWith('FATAL:') -and $_ -ne 'FATAL: SystemCallError: The interface is unknown. - RegisterEventSource'}
```

This will get all the lines that being with "FATAL:" but that don't equal "FATAL: SystemCallError: The interface is unknown. - RegisterEventSource"

Comment: All what lines? I've tried it in PowerShell 2.0 and 5.0 and it works as expected. Perhaps your log file is writing everything to a single line? Or maybe you have a typo?